# how to remove deletation confirmation in TbGridView

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-booster

Where to skip, replace or remove deletation confirmation in `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `TbButtonColumn` extends `CButtonColumn`, it should be possible by setting the [`deleteConfirmation`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn/#deleteConfirmation-detail) property to `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much  `'deleteConfirmation'=> false`